# Count multidimmensional array values by same array value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

Let's assume this scenario. We have multidimmensional $products array like this. 2 products, but 3 attributes and different cart_quantity for every one.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_product] => 1
            [id_product_attribute] => 5
            [cart_quantity] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_product] => 620
            [id_product_attribute] => 784
            [cart_quantity] => 8
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_product] => 1
            [id_product_attribute] => 12
            [cart_quantity] => 3
        )
)
```

How I can sum all of $product['cart_quantity'] for each array entry with same id_product that I would have result like this:

```
Array
(
     [1] => 4 // 1 + 3
     [620] => 8
)
```

I am really sorry about thread title I can't even form what I want to achieve without showing this in example above.

Comment: Have you tried `foreach()`? If not, i can write you an example with documentation

Comment: But how I can check that id_product was in foreach? This id_product will be random all the time. I can't use in foreach if ($value['id_product'] == 1) because this will be random in all of the carts.

Comment: I'll write an example ;-). One moment. Or is Siddharth his answer enough?

Comment: @RonnieOosting -  Siddharth is not working for me.

Comment: @ErykWróbel `$result[$value['id_product']] = ...`

Comment: Glad to read you've got working code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple `foreach` loop. Use `$product['product_id']` as the key in the result array, which you simply add to when you get a duplicate ID.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $id = $product['product_id'];
    $quant = $product['cart_quantity'];
    if (isset($result[$id])) {
        $result[$id] += $quant;
    } else {
        $result[$id] = $quant;
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly. I didn't even thought about such a simple and clever solution. I have to memorize this case to use it in future. Thank You.

http://codepad.org/LDCD8Wu0

Comment: If you're programming by memorizing snippets like this, you're not doing it right. You need to learn general principles and how to combine them to solve problems. Otherwise, it's like being only able to drive to places you've been to before.

Comment: I mean I will remember that I can use array values as array keys in foreach - I always keep forgeting about that. I know what You mean and I totally agree that it is not idea of learning programming.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try using following way..

```
$totals = array();
foreach ($main as $row) {
  $product = $row['id_product'];
  $quantity = $row['cart_quantity'];
  $totals[$product] += $quantity;
}
```